# MySQL Workbench not importing full excel sheet

Tags: mysql, workbench

Can someone please look at my code to see if there are any problems. I can import the excel sheet using Import wizard, but when I try to 'Load Data Infile' using the exact same settings, only part of the sheet is imported.

TEXT = text, INT = number, DOUBLE = numer with two decimal places.

My excel sheet does have some blank cells and I would like these to be uploaded.

```
CREATE TABLE wides (
    MDate TEXT,
    TCode TEXT,
    TName TEXT,
    CourseCode TEXT,
    Rail TEXT,
    Weather TEXT,
    GoingDescription TEXT,
    GoingValue DOUBLE,
    Peno DOUBLE,
    RNo INT,
    Dist INT,
    TABNO INT,
    Name TEXT,
    Rail1200 DOUBLE,
    Rail1000 DOUBLE,
    Rail800 DOUBLE,
    Rail600 DOUBLE,
    Rail400 DOUBLE,
    Rail200 DOUBLE,
    RailFin DOUBLE,
    Wides1200 DOUBLE,
    Wides1000 DOUBLE,
    Wides800 DOUBLE,
    Wides600 DOUBLE,
    Wides400 DOUBLE,
    Wides200 DOUBLE,
    WidesFin DOUBLE,
    WR1200 DOUBLE,
    WR1000 DOUBLE,
    WR800 DOUBLE,
    WR600 DOUBLE,
    WR400 DOUBLE,
    WR200 DOUBLE,
    WRFIN DOUBLE,
    WindSpeed INT,
    WindDir INT,
    MeetingId INT,
    RaceId INT,
    HorseId INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (HorseId)
);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/Users/name/Desktop/WidesTest.csv'
INTO TABLE wides
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: Could it be that you create a tables called `wides` and try and load a table called `wides3`??

Comment: Thats just a mistype

Comment: \r\n perhaps...

Comment: What does that do? It didn't work